# Add related field instance from admin panel in Django

Tags: django, model, admin

Let's say I want to have 3 such classes:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # ...

class Author(models.Model):
    # ...

class BookAuthor(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

What I want is to be able to add (and view those added) from the admin panel of `Book` model. -How- can I do this in Django?

I think the elegant way to do this is to implement views in a different app. But this project will only be used by admins as a data collection tool. So I don't want to implement a user interface, therefore handle everything from the admin panel. So is this (linking models) possible with Django's admin?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In `admin.py` you should have: `admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)` and `admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)` and `admin.site.register(BookAuthor, BookAuthorAdmin)`. You can define `BookAdmin`, `AuthorAdmin` and `BookAuthorAdmin` in `admin.py` and pass to each of them `pass`. Don't forget to also add a view if you want to render some custom template.

Comment: @Alexander looks like an answer :)

Comment: @Alexander thanks, but I would really appreciate if you could post this as an answer with the code sample. Thanks again !

Comment: I'm on mobile now, but I'll add an answer as soon as I can. Btw, the actual answer seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions would be to use `Inline`s in your admin views ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin )

You could do something like the following in your `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from ... import Book, BookAuthor, Author

class BookAuthorInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BookAuthor
    extra = 1
    raw_id_fields = ( "book", "author", ) 

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = [
        BookAuthorInline,
    ]
```

In this way you don't insert "directly" all the data in the Book admin form, but it pops up windows where you can insert data. It is a good compromise (IMO) between controlling the workflow for inserting data, and writing few lines of code.

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks like what I want, but I wonder if it lists the previously added (for that Book) BookAuthor objects in BookAdmin? Anyway, I will try and see :)

Comment: Yes, it does. Also, my example is about TabularInline but you can consider also StackedInline, as you prefer

Comment: It works! One final question though, in the initial phase (when the Book is created but no BookAuthors are assigned) , I see 3 boxes (so by default it adds 3 authors). -How- can I make that default number 1, or 0? So it only adds one author when I want. Is it possible?

Comment: Adding extra = 1 , or 0 , in your inline should do the job